# android how do i call this class from mainactivity

Tags: android

how do i call this class from mainactivity ? can anybody help me out am stuck as i am trying to learn thanks will appreciate it if u can help me on this one cheers.

```
package httpp.myapplication;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    private static final String GET_URL = "file:///C:/2-click%20run/index.html";

    private static final String POST_URL = "file:///C:/2-click%20run/home.html";

    private static final String POST_PARAMS = "userName=Pankaj";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        sendGET();
        System.out.println("GET DONE");
        sendPOST();
        System.out.println("POST DONE");
    }

    private static void sendGET() throws IOException {
        URL obj = new URL(GET_URL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("GET request not worked");
        }

    }

    private static void sendPOST() throws IOException {
        URL obj = new URL(POST_URL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        // For POST only - START
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("POST request not worked");
        }
    }

}
```

am not sure how to call this from MainActivity

Comment: it's a very common Class calling. . like the ones you do in other java classes

Comment: why is this tagged android ?]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have some sort of public methods to make this a usable class outside of itself. Set `sendGET()` and `sendPOST()` to public methods instead of private.

Then in your MainActivity, to get:

```
HttpURLConnectionExample.sendGET();
```

to post:

```
HttpURLConnectionExample.sendPOST();
```

It is the same way you would call any other class and because sendGET and sendPOST are static you do not have in allocate a new object of HttpURLConnectionExample like:

```
HttpURLConnectionExample httpURLConnectionExample = new HttpURLConnectionExample();
```

Comment: when i use   HttpURLConnectionExample.sendGET();    says  sendGet has private access in httpp.myapplication.HttpURLConnectionExample

Comment: Updated my answer. Also, when doing any network connectivity you have to do it outside of your UIThread.

Comment: nate  i stil  get says sendGet has private access in httpp.myapplication.HttpURLConnectionExample